# i am confused on how to make the sessionStorage. transfer arrays across different web pages

Tags: javascript

i am new to this site and JavaScript and am trying to build a fake username and password log in site. i want people to be able to make a username and password on one page and then log on in another. for now the username and password creation portion is limited to premade usernames and passwords for now. i am trying to use the sessionStorage. method to retrieve a defined variable from one web page and bring the data to another page. i am having trouble getting the username and password to the other page in an array with the sessionStorage. method which is what i think the problem is. please explain in grate simple detail for i remind you i am new to this. thank you!

this is the code for the page where the variables are defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
create account
</title>


<script>
sessionStorage.setItem("username1", ["bob", "sam"]);
sessionStorage.setItem("password1", ["lol", "jk"]);

</script>


</head>

<body>

</body>


</html>
```

this is the code for the page with the log in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
log on page
</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.myform.username.value;
    var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = sessionStorage.getItem("username1");
    var pwArray = vsessionStorage.getItem("password1");

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";

    if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password. " +
               "You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    }

    else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}
</script>

    <style>

    p.log_on{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
</style>





</head>


<body>


<form name = "myform">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="username"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="pword">
    <input type="button" value="Check In" name="Submit" onclick="validate()">
  </p>
</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Session storage should remain exist until the session is over.

Comment: You might want to `JSON.stringify` before `sessionStorage.setItem`, and  then `JSON.parse` when `sessionStorage.getItem`: https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/web-storage/Storage/setItem

Comment: i would like the answer to be in JavaScript if possible

Answer (score 1):

```
first file:
...
sessionStorage.setItem("username1", JSON.stringify(["bob", "sam"]));
sessionStorage.setItem("password1", JSON.stringify(["lol", "jk"]));
...

second file:
...
var unArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("username1"));
var pwArray = JSON.parse(vsessionStorage.getItem("password1"));
...
```